# Pytorch nn.functional.batch_norm for 2D input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I am currently implementing a model on which I need to change the running mean and standard deviation during test time. As such, I assume the `nn.functional.batch_norm` would be a better choice than the `nn.BatchNorm2d`

However, I have batches of images as input, and am currently not sure how to take in the images. How would I apply `nn.functional.batch_norm` on batches of 2D images?

The current code I have is this, I post this even though this is not correct:

```
mu = torch.mean(inp[0])
stddev = torch.std(inp[0])
x = nn.functional.batch_norm(inp[0], mu, stddev, training=True, momentum=0.9)
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JakubLangr it's been a long time since I had a look at this. Not sure. I can give you an upvote for a question of urs tho if u have sth similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that 2D batchnorm performs the same normalization for each channel. i.e. if you have a batch of data with shape (N, C, H, W) then your mu and stddev should be shape (C,). If your images do not have a channel dimension, then add one using `view`.

**Warning:** if you set `training=True` then `batch_norm` computes and uses the appropriate normalization statistics for the argued batch (this means we don't need to calculate the mean and std ourselves). Your argued mu and stddev are supposed to be the running mean and running std for all training batches. These tensors are updated with the new batch statistics in the `batch_norm` function.

```
# inp is shape (N, C, H, W)
n_chans = inp.shape[1]
running_mu = torch.zeros(n_chans) # zeros are fine for first training iter
running_std = torch.ones(n_chans) # ones are fine for first training iter
x = nn.functional.batch_norm(inp, running_mu, running_std, training=True, momentum=0.9)
# running_mu and running_std now have new values
```

If you want to just use your own batch statistics, try this:

```
# inp is shape (N, C, H, W)
n_chans = inp.shape[1]
reshaped_inp = inp.permute(1,0,2,3).contiguous().view(n_chans, -1) # shape (C, N*W*H)
mu = reshaped_inp.mean(-1)
stddev = reshaped_inp.std(-1)
x = nn.functional.batch_norm(inp, mu, stddev, training=False)
```